# I can not figure it out

Tags: java

I have the following requirements for my program:

- Write a program that reads an arbitrary number of integers in the range 1 to 50 from the keyboard and then outputs how many of each
  value were read.
- Do not output zero counts.
- Prompt the user for inputs as shown in the sample run.
- Let the user enter 0 to terminate input.
- Any other value outside the range 1 to 50 should get an error message.

I have done this so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Countingintegers
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] inputArray = new int[51];
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] frequency = new int[50];
        for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
        {
                  System.out.println("Input: ");
                  inputArray[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
                  if (inputArray[i] > 0 || inputArray[i] <= 50)
            {
                         ++frequency[inputArray[i]];
            }
                            else
            {
                            break;
            }

        }
        System.out.printf("%s%10s%n", "Number", "Frequency");
        for (int number = 1; number < frequency.length; number++)
               System.out.printf("%6d%10d%n", number, frequency[number]);

    }


}
```

Whether all my goals achieved?

Comment: Do you know about arrays? If you don't, look up how arrays work in java.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. What previous research have you done? Show us your code that you can't you figure out so we can help you. Our site is not meant to be used for arbitrary code requests.

Comment: I can't think of a more non-descriptive title on SO than "I can not figure out".

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] inputArray = new int[51];
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  int[] frequency = new int[50];
  for(int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++)
  {

Comment: @JayPatel, update your post please. And explain what you're stuck on.

Comment: "Write a program that reads an arbitrary number of integers". Your program is reading 51 integers. I don't see the purpose of `inputArray` altogether.

Comment: `if (inputArray[i] > 0 || inputArray[i] <= 50)` you're using `|| (or)` which with the given expressions will always return true. You need to use `&& (and)` instead

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this easily using `Map`. If you use a `TreeMap`, the inputs will be sorted. I would also suggest not placing all of your code in a main method. You should create public methods within your class and create an instance of the class to call methods upon, keeping the code in your main at a minimum and at most for the purpose of gathering input.

Here is an example, leveraging Maps for tracking the number of occurrences:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.util.*;

    public class Countingintegers{
        private int min, max;
        private Map<Integer,Integer> inputs = new TreeMap<>();

        public Countingintegers(int min, int max){
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public void addInt(Integer value) throws IllegalArgumentException{
             if(value < min || value > max){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
            if(inputs.containsKey(value)){
                inputs.put(value, inputs.get(value)+1);
            }
            else{
                inputs.put(value, 1);
            }
        }

        public void printCounts(){
            System.out.printf("%s%10s%n", "Number", "Frequency:");
            System.out.println(inputs);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int totalInputs = 50;
            int numIntsLoaded = 0;
            int input = -1;
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            Countingintegers counter = new Countingintegers(1, 50);

            while(numIntsLoaded < totalInputs && input != 0){
                System.out.println("Input a number between 1-50, or 0 to exit (" + (totalInputs-numIntsLoaded) + " to go):");
                try{
                    input = keyboard.nextInt();
                    counter.addInt(input);
                    numIntsLoaded++;
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("You entered an invalid input. Please try again!");
                    keyboard.nextLine();
                }
            }
            counter.printCounts();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My comments in the code will help you, your code was a pretty solid try. You just really over complicated it. Try to think more simply next time. You only need one array for this,

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Countingintegers {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Hi my name is COMMENTS please use me
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    //Please name your scanner objects scanner, its not for you but for other programmers. Gives us a headache when you dont.
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    //You only need one array...
    int[] frequency = new int[50];
    System.out.println("Input: ");

    //This for loop goes through 51 iterations of our array.
    for (int i = 0; i < 51; i++) {
        //Make a num variable so you do not have to keep on typing scanner.nextInt(), also I recomend you get familiar with variable scope.
        Integer num = scanner.nextInt();
        //You originally made this statement incorrectly. It needs to be between 0 and 50 right? || is for or (explicit) you better learn what explicit and implict for || (bitwise or) is too while your learning...
        if (num > 0 && num <= 50)
            //frequency[num] just represents the slot in the frequency array. A tip, an array will give you zeros if you don't assign numbers to all the slots. So frequency[10], the 11th slot in your array will be equal to zero when you create it.
            frequency[num] = frequency[num] + 1;
        //In programming your not really supposed to use breaks (I have honestly no idea why, but all the senior programmers keep telling me so...), but you are def a beginner so don't worry about it for now.
        if (num== 0)    break;

    }

    //The rest is history
    System.out.printf("%s%10s%n", "Number", "Frequency");
    for (int number = 1; number < frequency.length; number++)
        System.out.printf("%6d%10d%n", number, frequency[number]);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code:

```
if (inputArray[i] > 0 || inputArray[i] <= 50)
{
    ++frequency[inputArray[i]];
}
else
{
    break;
}
```

with this one:

```
if (inputArray[i] == 0) {
    break;
}
if (inputArray[i] < 0 || inputArray[i] > 50) {
    System.out.printf("Value enterd ouy of range [1-50]!");
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value enterd ouy of range [1-50]!");
}
++frequency[inputArray[i]];
```

It will

> `terminate input`

on 0 inputs and throw exception if the input value out of the expected range.